# Displaying Computer Name at Application Startup

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

We would like to display the name of the computer being used on our application without having to click on a label or use of a messege box.

```
Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    Label2.Text = My.Computer.Name
End Sub
```

The code above works but only when you click on the label.

How do we get it to just display as plan text.

Comment: use the constructor of your dialog and do your assignment there. When you create a instance of the dialog the Label is set to the Computer.Name

Answer (score 1):

```
  Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
        Label1.Text = My.Computer.Name
    End Sub
```

Comment: you can try form activated event in windows form

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to the window containing the label and assign the text in there.

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    Label1.Text = My.Computer.Name
End Sub
```